# "Reject with message" disappeared from the incoming call screen on Samsung S2 Plus?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, 4.2-jelly-bean, call-screening

I have Android 4.2.2 running on Samsung S2 Plus. I suppose that an update modified the configuration and now, when the phone is ringing for an incoming call I don't see anymore the option "Reject call with message".

For example: see screenshot below, you would find the  option "Reject call with message" option:

[image: Screenshot_Incoming_call]

<sub>Screenshot - Incoming call (Click to enlarge image)</sub>

Any idea on how to restore it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *"Reject call with message"* disappeared since I turned off the **"Messaging"** app (i.e., the standard SMS app) because I was using a different SMS app (Textra).

Re-enabling **"Messaging"** the *"Reject call with message"* is back.

Maybe this trick can be used if you want to disable the *"Reject call with message"* feature.